# Django use urls with same ending

Tags: python, django

I ahve a django project with the application `web-api` and the following url configuration:

main project `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('web-api/', include('webapi.urls')),
]
```

application `web-api/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<param1:param1>/summary', Param1Summary.as_view()),
    path('<param1:param1>/item/<int:id>/summary', ItemView.as_view()),
]
```

The `/web-api/param1/summary` endpoint works but `/web-api/param1/item/12121/summary` does not work and returns a 404 status code.

If I change the `<param1:param1>/item/<int:id>/summary'` to `<param1:param1>/item/<int:id>/whatever`, in the `web-api/url.py` I get the desired results.

I have tried using url regex without succees.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Not an general answer but worked in my case.**

Changing the order of the urls solved the issue. The urls in `web-api/urls.py` had to be in the following order:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:param1>/item/<int:pk>/summary', ItemView.as_view()),
    path('<str:param1>/summary', Param1Summary.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can reorder the urls in this way and add name spaces so you can call them from html template or from other views as well:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('summary/<param1:param1>', Param1Summary.as_view(), name='summary_parm')
    path('summary/<param1:param1>/item/<int:id>', ItemView.as_view(),  name='summary_item'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to keep the urls as they are because i do not want to cause breaking changes nor introduce inconsistencies between the API urls. (One of the urls is already used by clients)

Answer (score 0):

Update your application web-api's `urls.py` like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<param1:param1>/item/<int:id>/summary', ItemView.as_view()),
    path('<param1:param1>/summary', Param1Summary.as_view()),
]
```

Just swap their sequence, this will work.

Answer (score -2):

First, "param1" is not a valid url parameter type ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)), so you probably wanted to use `'<str:param1>/summary'` and `'<str:param1>/item/<int:pk>/summary'`.

Second, you should name the url variable "pk" as mentioned in [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#detailview-working-with-a-single-django-object), and not "id".

> it looks for pk and slug keyword arguments as declared in the URLConf, and looks the object up either from the model attribute on the view, or the queryset attribute if that’s provided

It should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:param1>/summary', Param1Summary.as_view()),
    path('<str:param1>/item/<int:pk>/summary', ItemView.as_view()),
]
```

Alternatively, you can set the `pk_url_kwarg = "id"` on your view to let the `get_object()` method know how to query for the object. [See in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. When using `id` (as is) but changing the word `summary` from `<param1:param1>/item/<int:pk>/summary` to any other word, everything works fine. So I guess the `id` is not the problem here